# TLang doesn't translate my components text in Delphi Firemonkey Multi Device Project

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey

On Both Android and iOS the TLang component doesn't translate my components text properties. They all have AutoTranslate property enabled.

I've tried to set the language manually by settings 'AutoSelect' to 'False' and then set the 'Lang' property to my desired language.

My components keep their default language. Even if I change the device Language itself.

Does anyone know what i'm missing here?

Most of my component use a custom 'stylelookup',
is it possible this conflicts with the autotranslate?

**UPDATE**

It's not the custom stylelookups. I've deleted my Stylebook and tried it with all the default styles. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you look at the [documented example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FMXTLang_(Delphi))?

Comment: @LURD yes i have.